# Drupal file manager that shows relations to content

Tags: 7, files

Is there module or simple way to show file relations to content with file manager like elfinder or any other? I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

I had that need recently for sorting my images since their file names were weird. What I ended up doing was to create a View of files, with relation to content that used the field that the file was assigned to.

After you do that you can either add the content's fields and properties (like title, nid, etc) and/or group by them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's the easiest solution, but it won't solve my problem. I'll write what I did once I have decided.